# how to plot shaded region around a line using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to plot a shaded region around a line using ggplot. The two data-sets are not directly related and I am doing some comparison between the two. Basically, I wish to plot the output which results from code below, along with shaded region having minimum and maximum y-axis values as entered in the variables 'lower_region_values' and 'upper_region_values'.

Please help me with this issue.

Reproducible code starts here

```
library("ggplot2")
plotName <- 'Comparison of latitudinal averages'

xlims <- c(65,80) # x axis extent

input_df <- structure(list(flux = c(0.08733913, 0.1015934, 
      0.1244135, 0.1390303,0.08417182,   0.02371609), 
      model = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L),.Label = 
      c("CASA_GFED_Optimized"),  class = "factor"), lat = 
      c(79, 77, 75, 73, 71, 69)), .Names = c("flux","model",  
      "lat"),row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

 lower_region_values<-c(-0.002157493,-0.004465291,-0.376925852,
     -0.312737571,-0.327533801,  -0.299551351)

 upper_region_values<-c(1.943331e-06,1.758454e-04,3.183347e-01,
      2.442368e-01,1.206353e-  01,1.572531e-02)

 sd_input_lower$model <- factor(sd_input_lower$model, 
      levels=levels(input_df$model))
 sd_input_upper$model <- factor(sd_input_upper$model, 
      levels=levels(input_df$model))
```

NEED a shaded region using the values in two vectors: lower_region_values and upper_region_values

```
 chart <- ggplot(input_df, aes(x=lat, group=model, 
      colour=model, fill=model)) +

# geom_ribbon(data = sd_input_upper, aes(ymin = -sd, ymax=sd), alpha=0.5) +

 geom_line(aes(y=flux), size=1.0) + 
      opts(title=plotName,legend.position='bottom') +
      scale_x_continuous('Latitude',limits=xlims) +   
      scale_y_continuous(expression(paste('Latitudinal average of NEE ', 
      (g~C~m^{-2}/day)))) +
      scale_colour_discrete(name='Model') +
      scale_fill_discrete(name='Model')

 print(chart)
```

Comment: Can you please work at rephrasing this question, into more of a question?

Comment: I need to plot a line and also plot an area around the line. The line values are not related in any way with the boundary points of the area. Coordinates for line are given in variable: 'input_df' and the region needs to be plotted using values in two vectors: 'lower_region_values' and 'upper_region_values'.

Comment: If you are having issues with multiple parts of the API then maybe you should ask multiple questions.

Comment: in that case, can you help in plotting a line and area around it?  line_data<-c(0.08733913, 0.1015934, 0.1244135, 0.1390303,0.08417182,  0.02371609)  and region data from the two '_region_value' vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the regions for shading into the same data.frame, because it is easier to do ggplots if they are all in the same object.  My resulting plot looks a little funny to me so I think we need to make certain that when we add these regions in, they are matching the x-axis values properly in their rows.

```
input_df$lower_region_values<-c(-0.002157493,-0.004465291,-0.376925852,
     -0.312737571,-0.327533801,  -0.299551351)

input_df$upper_region_values<-c(1.943331e-06,1.758454e-04,3.183347e-01,
      2.442368e-01,1.206353e-01,1.572531e-02)
```

If I understand your goals correctly, I would basically do what you were doing, but move the aes() around a little:

```
chart<-
      ggplot(input_df, aes(x=lat, y=flux,group=model)) +
      geom_line(size=1.0,colour="red") + 
      opts(title=plotName,legend.position='bottom') +
      scale_x_continuous('Latitude',limits=xlims) +   
      scale_y_continuous(expression(paste('Latitudinal average of NEE ', 
      (g~C~m^{-2}/day)))) +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_region_values, 
      ymax=upper_region_values), colour="blue", fill="blue",alpha=0.5)

 print(chart)
```

You seem to be using an older version of ggplot2, so if you're still learning ggplot, I would update and learn the new one, which has some significant changes.

Comment: that works well, thanks. Just a quick question, how can I change the color of the line and area?

Comment: right now, colour and fill are getting assigned at the beginning of the ggplot function to reflect the variable model.  You could omit that colour and fill assignment there.  Also leave out the scale_colour_discrete() and the scale_fill_discrete() and instead put, for example, a colour="blue" inside the geom_line or a fill="green" and colour="green" in the geom_ribbon.  I have edited the above plot to do that.